# Not getting the webhook for a comment on a post from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on getting a webhook into my backend when a user writes a comment on a page.

As instructed in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies, I tried to do it but failed.

These are the steps I followed.

1. Got 'page_show_list' and 'page_manage_metadata' permission
2. Went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and got a 'page Access token selecting the correct page. Here I selected 'page_show_list', 'page_manage_metadata', and 'page_messaging' permission to generate the page access token. Screenshot9 shows my permissions and page selection for page access token generation.

[image]

3. Then I started my backend with that page access token.
4. In the Facebook Developer portal -> webhooks -> page, I added the backend as the callback URL. It registered successfully without any error.
5. I tested the webhook manually by clicking the Developer portal ->webhooks -> page ->feed ->test button and by backend got the test content.
6. Went to the page, added a comment to an existing post, but my backend is not getting anything.

Have I done any mistakes in the middle?

Comment: Did you actually subscribe for updates from your specific page? It sounds like you might have skipped that step.

Comment: Also, the documentation page you referred to, says you also need `pages_manage_metadata` permission.

Comment: @CBroe what did you mean by subscribing to the page. I generated the page access token, put it in the backend, restart the backend, registered the webhook on the page with the URL of the backend. isn't it the procedure to subscribe to the page events to the backend?

I have already for pages_manage_metadata permission

Comment: I am talking about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#configure-webhooks-product - can’t tell from your description, whether you actually performed this step for the specific page in question, or not.

Comment: @CBroe Yes I added it from my facebook app

Comment: Is your app live, or still in dev mode? And if the latter, are you testing this with a user account that has a role in the app?

Comment: It is live and i am testing that as the admin role

Comment: I subscribed to the page 'feed' field manually and it works. thanks for the insight

Answer (score -1):

Try to update your facebook page subscription.

FYI *https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You have to subscribe the page with reference to your FB app using your page access token received from the same FB app.
Please review https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/